# My SQL query to retrieve 4 columns based on unique records from two columns

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm trying to write a correct query for MySQL to retrieve values from 4 columns (from, to, content, date or all if that's easier) based on 2 columns being unique in the same table. The idea is to retrieve a list of only last messages sent and received by a user X

TABLE

```
msg_id|msg_from|msg_to|msg_new|msg_content|date
1       user1     sw1     1     message1    2014-02-06
2       user1     sw1     1     message2    2014-02-06
3       user1     sw3     0     message3    2014-02-06
4       user1     sw5     0     message4    2014-02-06
5       sw2       sm2     1     message5    0000-00-00
6       sw2       sm4     1     message6    2014-02-20
7       sw1       user1   1     message7    2014-02-20
8       user1     sw5     1     message8    2014-02-20
```

My last attempt :

```
SELECT t1.* FROM (SELECT MAX(msg_id) AS nr, msg_from, msg_to 
    FROM com_msg GROUP BY msg_from) AS t2 
    INNER JOIN com_msg t1 ON t1.msg_from=t2.msg_from AND t1.msg_id=t2.nr 
    WHERE t1.msg_to='sw1' OR t1.msg_from='sw1'
```

which returns :

```
2| user1|sw1  |1|message2|2014-02-06
7| sw1  |user1|1|message7|2014-02-20
```

but should only return :

```
7| sw1  |user1|1|message7|2014-02-20
```

Comment: I'm confused... your original post says, "The idea is to retrieve a list of only last messages sent and received by a user X", but your example shows only 1 message.  Do you want A message or 2 messageS?

Comment: i think you are looking for the last message for each conversation? in this case it's just one, but there could be more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understant your question correctly, this query should return what you need:

```
SELECT com_msg.*
FROM com_msg INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(msg_id) max_id
                         FROM com_msg
                         WHERE 'sw1' IN (msg_from, msg_to)
                         GROUP BY
                           CASE WHEN msg_from!='sw1' THEN msg_from
                                ELSE msg_to END) m
     ON com_msg.msg_id = m.max_id
```

IDs needs to be ordered, otherwise you should use MAX(date)

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8d4e/1).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to wrap this with another query, because your where clause is showing you records where either the to or the from equal the user. I'm not a MySQL guru, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
select top 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT t1.* FROM (
        SELECT MAX(msg_id) AS nr, msg_from, msg_to 
        FROM com_msg 
        GROUP BY msg_from
    ) AS t2 
    INNER JOIN com_msg t1 ON t1.msg_from=t2.msg_from AND t1.msg_id=t2.nr 
    WHERE t1.msg_to='sw1' OR t1.msg_from='sw1'
)
ORDER BY date DESC
```

This will return the most recent entry from your results based on the date.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for just a single record returned of the last email like your example shows, this should do it...

```
Select TOP 1 msg_from, msg_to, msg_content, date
From com_msg
Where msg_from='sw1' OR msg_to='sw1'
ORDER BY msg_id DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your input, sorry for confusion it is in fact just last msg regardless of its being send or received by user X, tried TOP 1 query before but get MYSQL error every time